# Mark changes since last edition with bars in the margin

Tags: changes, highlighting

I would like to mark the parts of my document that have changed since the last revision with vertical bars in the margin.  Is there a package to help with this?

Is there a tool that can compare two files and automatically add bars in the appropriate places, or do I have to insert markup manually?

Answer (score 17):

Marking changes:

- the [changebar package](http://ctan.org/pkg/changebar) allows marking changes by bars. Not automatically, it has to be done by commands:`\cbstart` and `\cbend`. Change may can be nested within each other and with other environments, they can be colored and can cross page boundaries.
- the [chbar package](http://ctan.org/pkg/chbar) is an alternative for plain TeX.

Comparing files:

- Since LaTeX files are text documents
  you could use any [diff tool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff)
  comparing txt files and printing out
  the differences.

Answer (score 10):

See latexdiff on ctan:

> Latexdiff is a Perl script for visual mark up and revision of significant differences between two latex files. Various options are available for visual markup using standard latex packages such as color . Changes not directly affecting visible text, for example in formatting commands, are still marked in the latex source. A rudimentary revision facilility is provided by another Perl script, latexrevise, which accepts or rejects all changes. Manual editing of the difference file can be used to override this default behaviour and accept or reject selected changes only.