# Is it worth switching from Dropbox to a "real" versioning system?

Tags: revision-control, git, dropbox, mercurial

I currently use Dropbox for storing my TeX projects, but have been tempted to switch to a "real" revision control system, like Mercurial or Git, lately.

If it is worthwhile to switch, what would be some tips and pointers? My top switching question is should I use GitLab or Bitbucket to host in a private repository, or should I set up the remote repository on my server?

Comment: Several closely related questions has been asked already: e.g. [this one](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1158/what-version-control-system-should-i-use-for-my-latex-documents?rq=1) and the ones it links to.  On the one hand, they’ve received several answers; on the other, they’ve been generally deemed off-topic (very open-ended and subjective, and not particularly specific to TeX).  If you’ve read those, and (a) you still have questions and (b) you think yours is more on-topic than they were, would you consider editing your question to clarify what you’re more specifically after?

Comment: The tl;dr though is: it depends a lot on what you’re working on with TeX — how collaboratively, how complex (e.g. maintaining journal + personal + other versions of a paper in parallel), and so on, and also how confident you are with the more technical parts of the software ecosystem (i.e. does working from the command-line intimidate you at all?).  But I and most people I know who *have* switched to real VC feel it was completely worthwhile and we couldn’t imagine going back :-)

Comment: I mostly write by myself, sometimes with a separate editor at the end.  It was using git repositories for programming that got me interested in possibly using them for my LaTeX projects.  Git is what I (sort-of) know, but I'm willing to learn Hg if it's better for this kind of work.

Comment: The right answer rather depends on what you are doing with your documents.  git allows easy creation of branches to try out new ideas, or alter parts of a project in parallel.  You can create branches, work on them separately, then merge them together etc.  Afaik you can't do this easily on Dropbox.  OTOH Dropbox is much simpler - you can generally just save and forget.

Comment: You can use Mercurial, Git etc. AND have it on Dropbox. I would heavily recommend to use a good version control system. I'm very happy with Mercurial and would recommend it if you don't need the extra features Git provides, which I  think so for LaTeX documents.